# Access VBA - Hide Labels, text box, buttons If = " "

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to hide make some labels, text boxes and buttons hidden:

```
If rst![RI] = "" Or IsNull(rst![RI]) Then
```

I have:

- A Label named "Label83"
- A Text box named "C1"
- A Text box named "Tex4"
- A Text box named "Text8"
- A button named "Command18"

[image]

So whenever I'm on PM200 and `If rst![RI] = "" Or IsNull(rst![RI])`
Then the listed label, text boxes and button should be hidden.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: .visible=(rst![RI] = "" Or IsNull(rst![RI])) ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as a minimum:

```
Me!Label83.Visible = Len(Nz(rst![RI].Value))
```

or, to play nice:

```
Me!Label83.Visible = CBool(Len(Nz(rst![RI].Value)))
```

For more controls, set a variable:

```
Dim Visible As Boolean
Visible = CBool(Len(Nz(rst![RI].Value)))
Me!Label83.Visible = Visible
Me!text8.Visible = Visible

' etc.
```

And do rename your controls to something meaningful, like: `lblCtransfer`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Btw, I didn't name them those awful names.